# ds3231 rtc module weekly alarm

Tags: arduino-uno, interrupt, rtc, ds3231-alarms

I have a ds3231 and Arduino UNO and I need to get an interrupt from ds3231 once a week for example every Fridays. I've searched a lot in the internet and forums but did not find any library or code that have weekly alarm or some of them that had, they didn't work well.
I also read the data sheet of ds3231 but didn't understand how to set the registers of it.
can anyone help?

Comment: check the DS3231 libraries in IDE in "Manage Libraries"

Comment: I never really like using the "alarm" function of the DS3231. I'd just check the data and time every loop (, or every few seconds). See if the day-of-week is different from the previous time I check. If so, and the day-of-week is Friday, run the code. This way you can have as many "alarms" as you want instead of using the (I think) two alarms in the DS3231.

Comment: Are you using the /INT/SQW pin of DS3231 to trigger the alarm?

Comment: @smajli  Yes Im using that.